# Office.onReady() always throws error in slower network

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

We have completed development of an Excel addin using the officejs API's. During the process of deploying it to App source we got a feedback that the addin shows blank screen when there is a slower internet connection. When we tried to debug it we got the following error ( when *3G Slow* option is set in chrome ).

Uncaught Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.

But the same addin works fine when the internet speed is decent. Below is the piece of code that we have used to bootstrap the angular application.

```
Office.onReady().then(function() {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

We are still not sure what went wrong but when we comment the single line inside the Office.onReady function and add consoles. It dosen't throw any error's ( I know this is irrelavent but still an observation which we made ). It would be great if someone could help us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it help to use any of the alternate syntaxes for onReady described in [Initialize add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in)? If not, does it help to use Office.initialize instead of onReady as described in the same article?

Comment: We have tried the different methods of using on ready ( promise, call back and after $('document').onReady ) and office.initialize also has the same effect

Comment: Are either `platformBrowserDynamic()` or `bootstrapModule(AppModule)` asynchronous?

Comment: Yes @RickKirkham

Comment: Try separating them into separate then methods like this: `Office.onReady()
.then(function() {
  var x = platformBrowserDynamic();
}).then(function (x) {
    x.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});`

Comment: hello @RickKirkham platformBrowser ( PlatformRef )  is a class initializer. bootstrapModule is a member of the class ( PlatformRef ). platformBrowserdynamic() is not a promise but bootstrapModule is a promise. I searched for the issue in server web forms and came to know that this is the common way of bootstrapping in angular ( Event Microsoft office.js docs for excel suggest the same )

Comment: Hello @RickKirkham we have resolved the issue by reducing the application size after build by adding the following lines in the build script '''ng build --base-href=/excel/ --prod=true --aot=true --buildOptimizer=true --extractCss=true --extractLicenses=true --optimization=true --output-hashing=all --sourceMap=true'''. After a long investigation we found out that application size has some impact in slower networks inside Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation my collegues found out that the application size had significant impact on loading the extension inside excel after adding the following line of code in build script we were able to fix this

```
ng build --base-href=/excel/ --prod=true --aot=true --buildOptimizer=true --extractCss=true --extractLicenses=true --optimization=true --output-hashing=all --sourceMap=true.
```

**Update**

**Previous size**

```
runtime.js.map - 6.17 kb
main.js.map - 1.69 Mb
polyfills.js.map - 148 kb
polyfillses5.js.map - 567 kb
styles.css.map - 177 kb
vendor.js.map - 7.71 mb
```

**After changing the build script**

```
runtime.js.map - 1.51kb
main.js.map - 1.9Mb
polyfills.js.map - 43.1kb
polyfillses5.js.map - 123kb
styles.css.map - 61.3kb
```

The vendor.js.map file is removed after changing the build script which we suspect is the reason for quick initial load of the application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a bit more? What was the application size before / what did you reduce it to solve the problem?

Comment: @MaviDomates I have updated the answer adding the size information. Hope it helps